# Run nose test, modify a global variable, and run the test again

Tags: python, nose

I am looking to run a test module twice, while modifying a global variable in between.

A stripped down version of the whole test suite looks something like this:

```
my_var = 'blah'

def test_x():
    assert my_var == 'blah'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose
    result = nose.runmodule()
    my_var = 'asdf'
    import nose
    result = nose.runmodule()
```

I am expecting the second run to fail. However, it seems that nose only runs the test once:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Is it possible to achieve what I intended in the main program?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to run the same test with different data inputs, you should look into parameterization.

With nose there is a [library](https://github.com/wolever/nose-parameterized) to do so, or you could write your method to do it. In your case, you really only need to iterate over your test cases and run the same assertion.

```
def test_x():
    test_cases = ['blah', 'asdf']
    for my_var in test_cases:
         assert my_var == 'blah'
```